# Sorting/Filtering by price React.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use the SELECT to sort by price but it not working

I select High Price but the items don't sort themselves by price

I have tried adding a value but it doesn't work :C

```
<Col lg="6" md="6" sm="6" xs="12" className="mb-5">
              <div className="sorting__widget text-end">
                <select className="w-50" onChange={selectedChangeFilter}>
                  <option value="all">Default</option>
                  <option value="high-price">High Price</option>
                  <option value="low-price">Low Price</option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </Col>

            {displayPage.map((item) => (
              <Col lg="3" md="4" sm="6" xs="6" key={item.id} className="mb-4">
                <ProductCard 
                item={item}
                products={products}
                searchProducts={searchProducts}
                searchValue={searchValue}/>
              </Col>
            ))}
```

This is the Javascript code

```
const selectedChangeFilter = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.target;
    if (value === "low-price") {
      const lowestPriceGoods = products.sort((el1, el2) =>
        el1.price.localeCompare(el2.price, undefined, { numeric: true })
      );
      setProductsInfo([...lowestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "highest price") {
      const highestPriceGoods = products.sort((el1, el2) =>
        el2.price.localeCompare(el1.price, undefined, { numeric: true })
      );
      setProductsInfo([...highestPriceGoods]);
    }
    if (value === "all") {
      setProductsInfo(products);
    }
  };


  const searchProducts = (products) => {
    if (searchValue.toLowerCase().trim() === "") {
      setProductsInfo(products);
    } else {
      const seekedItem = productsInfo.filter(
        (product) =>
          product.name.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue) ||
          product.category.toLowerCase().trim().includes(searchValue)
      );
      setProductsInfo(seekedItem);
    }
  };
```

These are my consts

```
const AllFoods = () => {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState ("");
  const [productsInfo, setProductsInfo] = useState([]);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(0);
```

Comment: The type of price is string?

Comment: Hey @Angel Hdz! The price is allocated on an individual component const products = [
  {
    id: "01",
    title: "Pineapple",
    price: 10.0,
    image01: product_01_image_01,
    image02: product_01_image_02,
    image03: product_01_image_03,
    category: "Fruits",

    desc: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Soluta ad et est, fugiat repudiandae neque illo delectus commodi magnam explicabo autem voluptates eaque velit vero facere mollitia. Placeat rem, molestiae error obcaecati enim doloribus impedit aliquam, maiores qui minus neque. ",
  },

Comment: can you try with return statements - suggestion.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].